# How to read the raw data of a file?

Tags: python, stack

Here is the method to check if the HTML tags are matched:

```
def is_matched_html(raw):

    """Return True if all HTML tags are properly match; False otherwise."""
    S = ArrayStack()
    j = raw.find('<')               # find first ’<’ character (if any)
    while j != -1:
        k = raw.find('>', j+1)       # find next ’>’ character
        if k == -1:
            return False            # invalid tag
        tag = raw[j+1:k]            # strip away < >
        if not tag.startswith('/'):  # this is opening tag
            S.push(tag)
        else:                       # this is closing tag
            if S.is_empty():
                return False        # nothing to match with
            if tag[1:] != S.pop():
                return False        # mismatched delimiter
        j = raw.find('<', k+1)      # find next ’<’ character (if any)
    return S.is_empty()             # were all opening tags matched?
```

And the attached pic [image]is the HTML data to be checked:

How could I check the above HTML data using the first given code?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: first of all, please post the HTML in raw format, second of all, why not use a tried and tested library for this?

Comment: @gold_cy probably because it's homework...

Comment: To call this code to check the file, you would do `print (is_matched_html(open("path\to\myinput.html").read()))`. That opens your file of HTML data, reads in its contents, then passes it as the argument `raw` to the function you present. Is that really what you meant to ask?

Comment: Hi BoarGules, this is exactly what I want. Thanks a lot!